# iOSでのiFrameのhistory.back()の挙動について

Tags: javascript, monaca, html5

monacaでスマホアプリを製作中です。
タブバーとナビゲーターを使って、TOPページ、ECページ、他数ページのアプリです。

ECページで、別ドメインのサイトをiFrameに埋め込み、進むボタンと戻るボタンをつけています。

```
<p id="iframe-back" class="iframe-control"><a href="JavaScript:frames['iFrame名'].history.back()"><ons-icon icon="ion-ios-arrow-back"></ons-icon></a></p>
<p id="iframe-forward" class="iframe-control"><a href="JavaScript:frames['iFrame名'].history.forward()"><ons-icon icon="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></ons-icon></a></p>
```

Androidでは挙動は正常なのですが、iOSで動かした時、TOPページから1ページ遷移し、
戻るボタンを押すと、アプリのトップに移動してしまいます。

お分かりの方おられましたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。